# Verify HBase snapshot caputred all data

Tags: hbase, snapshot, cloudera-cdh

When creating snapshots in HBase I received an error stating "Snapshot 'snapshot_name' wasn't completed in expectedTime:60000 ms.

However, when I then list my current snapshots I see that the snapshot that returned the error saying it was not completed in the expected time was actually created anyways.

How do I compare that snapshot to the source table (table I was taking a snapshot of) to verify that it created a complete snapshot of the source table?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the snapshot process cost a longer time then expected, related code is in `HbaseAdmin.snapshot`:

```
if (!done.getDone()) {
  throw new SnapshotCreationException("Snapshot '" + snapshot.getName()
      + "' wasn't completed in expectedTime:" + max + " ms", snapshot);
}
```

But the request is sent to server and the snapshot process begins already. If you want to check the stated of snapshot, you can check it on webUI, the URL like :

```
http://your-hmaster:60010/snapshot.jsp?name=your-snapshot-name
```

If you want to compare the data, you can clone the snapshot to another table first, and run a map-reduce job to compare.

Comment: Thanks, I have already cloned the snapshot to another table. I found something saying I could run the below command but do I run that from the command line in the hbase shell? If so, do I use the entire command or just the first line? If I need to use the part after "Usage:" I am not sure what to fill in there.

 hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter <tablename>

Usage: RowCounter [options] 
    <tablename> [          
        --starttime=[start] 
        --endtime=[end] 
        [--range=[startKey],[endKey]] 
        [<column1> <column2>...]
    ]

Comment: RowCounter http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rowcounter_example is just get the count of rows in specified table not compare the content of two tables. So you mean that you only want to compare the row count of cloned table and the original ? you can just run "count 'your-table'" in hbase shell if you want that...

Comment: "Count <tablename>" was what I originally tried but it was taking way too long & then failing. I found a command to return the count MUCH faster but the reduce job never runs. When it is finished it always says INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%. However, it still provides a row count. Does the reduce job need to run too though to get an accurate count?

Also, many of the jobs will return a result such as this:
INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%
INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_123456 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_123456
Job failed as tasks failed.

Comment: @N.Smith RowCounter actually run a job with mapper ```org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter$RowCounterMapper``` and without a reducer, the counter show at ```org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter$RowCounterMapper$Counters```  ```ROWS=$ROWNUM``` is accurate if there are no concurrent writes. If the job ends without message like ```completed successfully```, you should check the failure detail.